# Plot at sequential positions with repeated x-axis vaues

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to show the list below symmetrically based on the maximum value of x.

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1]
y = [123,233,320,381,403,376,314,225,119]
plt.plot(x,y)
```

Plotting this data, of course, looks like this:

[image]

But I want to look symmetrical like this:

[image]

Is there any way to make it like above, other than converting x data to string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to set those `x` values as tick labels not actual axis values:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1]
y = [123,233,320,381,403,376,314,225,119]
x_axis  = range(len(x))
plt.plot(x_axis,y)
_ = plt.xticks(x_axis, x)
```

[image]